# not work array interface to php

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am working with the Laravel framework and version php 5.5.12

```
<?php
namespace App\pattern;

interface status 
 { 

    const status = array( 
            "confirm"=> 1
            ,"unconfirm"=> 2
           ,"record"=> 3
   );
}
```

after use class

```
$r = $this::status['confirm'];
```

show error

> FatalErrorException in ContentController.php line 19: syntax error, unexpected '['

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `$this`, it's an interface.

you need to use it like:

```
$r = status::status['confirm'];
//     ^        ^ 
//     |        constant name 
//  interface name
//
echo $r;
```

And as strange as it might be, interfaces *do support* constants, as stated [here: php constants](http://php.net/manual/ro/language.oop5.constants.php)

In php 5.5 though, you can't have an `array` as a constant

You can check out https://3v4l.org/JbdJa and see it working as an interface call or inside a class implementing that interface

Comment: Thankful
I reviewed the problem version of the version php.5.6
Generally to define a array constants